# Formula Help for Flow that Calculates time spent in each "stage" on a custom Picklist field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I used this post: [How to track time spent in each stage of a custom detail object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375312/how-to-track-time-spent-in-each-stage-of-a-custom-detail-object/375386#375386)  which is very helpful. I am having issues with my formula.

I keep getting The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra '('. Can someone help with my syntax here?

```
TEXT({!$Record__Prior.Impact_Stage__c}) & " : " & TEXT({!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} - {!$Record__Prior.Last_Impact_Stage_Update__c}) * 24 & " hours"
```

Comment: the formula looks ok.  This is troubleshooting 101.  Just take out each part of the formula until you don't get a syntax error, and that will tell you which part is invalid.

Comment: I did that for an hour, can't get it to work.

Comment: That should only take 5 minutes to do.  Did you put the entire formula in your question?