# A way to track time spent on a custom Stage/Picklist in a custom Object

Tags: formula, sales-cloud, path

I'm helping in a Org that isn't using the Opportunity Object, they have a custom Object for this scenario. One of the fields is a picklist named "status" that is referenced by the Path at the top of the screen with different stages etc..

I need to create a solution to track how long it takes team members to complete a stage, ie.
the time it take to start in stage 2 then moving on to stage 3 and saving. I've seen a few ideas but haven't found the one to meet this requirement. Has anyone found a good solution to this? Or have an idea we can try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've set up something similar at my organization, adapted from [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375312/how-to-track-time-spent-in-each-stage-of-a-custom-detail-object). I set up a custom object, "Custom Opportunity Stage Event" which has the following fields (in addition to Opportunity Name, Account Name etc.): From Stage, To Stage, Stage Change Date, Stage Duration, Stage Moved By.

Stage Duration is calculated using a custom field on the custom opportunity object, 'Most Recent Stage Update Date':

- When the object is created, this field is written with the Created Date
- When the object moves between stages, this triggers a Flow which calculates Stage Duration as (CurrentDate - MostRecentStageUpdateDate)
- In the same flow, the CurrentDate is written to and updates MostRecentStageUpdateDate

Hope that helps!

Comment: That sounds like a really good solution. I also read the other article but couldn't get it to work quite right. How were you able to distinguish between the many stages? Is that inside the Flow?

Comment: Yes, in the flow builder, there is $Record.Stage and $Record_prior.Stage. $Record.Stage is "To Stage" and $Record_prior.Stage is "From Stage". Since these read from your custom object, that is all you need. Also note creates a Stage Change Event EVERY time a record moves between stages. Then you can report on "From Stage": the Stage Duration that we calculate is the time in the PREVIOUS stage which the record is moving from.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm going to start trying build this right now. I'm still fairly new and learning so I may come back for some advice! Are all those fields you created the same data type? Or are a few date/time, text etc..

Comment: From Stage and To Stage etc. can be TextArea, Stage Duration is a Number, the various Date fields can be either DateTime or Date, just be consistent. Or you will have to do some typecasting when you calculate Stage Duration.

Comment: Would you be able to share some screen shots of a few details inside your Flow? Just trying to peace it all together.